# KafkaListener NACK sleep timeout

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I'm using a @KafkaListener in batch mode with manual ack and therefore leverages the Acknowledgement parameter in the corresponding method to perform manual commits and batch retries. I see that the nack() method necessarily takes a sleep duration as parameter and the Javadoc states that the MAX between this value and pollTimeout will be used before resending the batch up to the specified index. What is the reasoning behind that ? I would like to have my new batch retried as soon as possible and I don't see use cases where one would voluntarily wait.
On the other hand, I didn't change the pollTimeout but put a 0ms delay as NACK sleep parameter and could observe that the retry was then nearly instantaneous.
Could it be possible to have more clarification on that ?

Answer (score 0):

It's a trade off between CPU usage when idle and responsiveness to situations like this.

You can just reduce the `pollTimeout` from its default 5000 (5 seconds) to something like 100ms.

The problem is that the thread is blocked in the poll until the poll times out, and only then can we call the listener. There is currently no async scheduled task to wake the listener after the nack delay before the poll times out. It's generally not a problem if you tune the poll timeout.

With a 0ms nack timeout, we don't go through the consumer pause/resume cycle, which is why that works.

It is a bit unusual, however, to want to retry immediately; generally transient problems (such as connectivity to a database) take some finite time to resolve.